# blockUI - change font-family & remove padded area on overlay?

Tags: blockui, jquery-blockui

Using blockUI. I looked through the options in the documentation, through the plugin itself, and even here on stackoverflow and I can't find where to change the font-family declaration for this. It appears to be using Times by default. Also, the font is displayed over a padded area. Is there a way I can remove that padded area part, I want only the text on top of the dimmed screen. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use message option for this.

Document here http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#options